# di2 front derailleur braze on for 105?

Tags: derailleur, braze-on

can [di2 front derailleur braze on adapter](http://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/ultegra-di2-clamp-band-sm-ad67m-31,8mm-28,6mm-56399/wg_id-6873) be used to mount 105 derailleur?

Comment: I don't see why not. In any case, its a cheap part, so there is little risk in trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should be fine, as the front derailleur braze on mount is universal